TypeScript Type Error When Transforming API Response Format to Different Format Using Select in useInfiniteQuery
Custom Hook Call
const { data } = useListInfiniteQuery({
  searchText: SearchText,
  dateRange: dateRange,
  select: getListItems,
});

Select Function
function getListItems({
  pageParams,
  pages,
}: InfiniteData<IListItems>): InfiniteData<IListItems> {
  const allItems = pages.flatMap((page) => page.items);
  const filterCount = transformFilterCount(pages[0]?.filterCount);// getting Error in this line
  return {
    pageParams,
    pages: [
      {
        items: allItems,
        filterCount,
      },
    ],
  };
}

Types and Transformation Function

export type FilterCountData = Record<string, Record<string, number>>;

export interface IFilterOption {
  label: string;
  count: number;
  value: string;
}

export interface IFilterCategory {
  name: string;
  options: IFilterOption[];
}

function transformFilterCount(
  filterCountData: FilterCountData | undefined,
): IFilterCategory[] {
  if (!filterCountData) {
    return [];
  }

  return Object.keys(filterCountData).map((key) => {
    const options: IFilterOption[] = Object.keys(filterCountData[key]).map(
      (subKey) => ({
        label: filterSectionTitle[subKey.toLowerCase()] ?? subKey,
        count: filterCountData[key][subKey] ?? 0,
        value: subKey.toLowerCase(),
      }),
    );

    return {
      name: filterSectionTitle[key] ?? key,
      options,
    };
  });
}

Error Message
Argument of type 'IFilterCategory[] | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FilterCountData | undefined'.
Type 'IFilterCategory[]' is not assignable to type 'FilterCountData'.
  Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'IFilterCategory[]'.

Is it valid to transform the filterCount data from the API response into a different format within the select function of a in React Query? If so, how can I resolve the type error that I'm encountering during this transformation? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.
API response
{
  "Fruits": {
    "apple": 93,
    "Banana": 4,
    "orange": 23
  },
  "Vegetable": {
    "Carrot": 23,
    "Beetroots": 23,
    "tamato": 45
  }
}

Desired Transformed Format
[
  {
    name: 'Fruits',
    options: [
      { label: 'apple', count: 93, value: 'apple' },
      { label: 'Banana', count: 4, value: 'Banana' },
      { label: 'orange', count: 23, value: 'orange' },
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Vegetable',
    options: [
      { label: 'Carrot', count: 23, value: 'Carrot' },
      { label: 'Beetroots', count: 23, value: 'Beetroots' },
      { label: 'tamato', count: 45, value: 'tamato' },
    ]
  }
];



Is it valid to transform the filterCount data from the API response into a different format within the select function of a in React Query?

Yes, this has always been valid at runtime. There was a typings issue specifically for useInfiniteQuery that was fixed in v5.
